# How to convert an image to byte[] using app engine image service?

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine

I m trying to use App engine`s Images service and I m stuck in the following:

The example that can be found on the site is the following:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.images.Image;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesService;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.Transform;

// ...
        byte[] oldImageData;  // ...

        ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();

        Image oldImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(oldImageData);
        Transform resize = ImagesServiceFactory.makeResize(200, 300);

        Image newImage = imagesService.applyTransform(resize, oldImage);

        byte[] newImageData = newImage.getImageData();
```

That s pretty much straightforward. My question is how to convert an image to a byte array before i feed it to the image service. I tried to use the service locally in my pc and app engine doesn't support the java.awt.image package. So i dont know how to create a byte array out of the image and vice versa. 
Anybody could help me out?

Thnx

Comment: What is the original source of your image? (e.g. was it from uploaded image, read from external file, fetched from Google Cloud Storage, etc?)

Comment: It s from Google Cloud Storage